# Why this is a generalization of Young's inequality?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, probability, inequality, young-inequality

The is the standard version of Young's inequality
$$ab \leq \frac{a^p}{p}+\frac{b^q}{q}$$
for $a,b,p,q >0$ and $$\frac{1}{p}+\frac {1}{q}=1$$

But there is another formula called generalization of Young inequality. Why it's a generalization?

---

let $f$ denote a real-valued, continuous and strictly increasing function on $[0, c]$ with $c > 0$ and $f(0) = 0$.

Let $f^{−1}$ denote the inverse function of $f$. Then, for all $a ∈ [0, c]$ and $b ∈ [0, f(c)]$,

$$ab \le \int_{0}^{a} f(x)dx + \int_{0}^{b}f^{-1}(x)dx$$

Comment: This is rather the 'integral' version of the inequality.

Answer (score 1):

$$\frac 1p + \frac 1q=1 \implies (p-1)(q-1)=1$$

Now let
$$f(x)=x^{p-1}$$
$$f^{-1}(x)=x^{\frac 1{p-1}}=x^{q-1}$$